# resize the image according to the portrait and landscape in jquerymobile?

Tags: jquery-ui, landscape, jquery-mobile, portrait

I have to add image on the header and background . Is it possible to set the image automatically resizing  according to the screen orientation  (portrait and Landscape). I set the image in portrait resolution , But when  i change the screen to Landscape  the image not resized. Can anyone give me some guidelines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support for this is built into jQuery Mobile.  There are two [Orientation Classes](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/api/mediahelpers.html) which are present depending on the current screen orientation:

```
.portrait {
    /* portrait orientation changes go here! */
}
.landscape {
    /* landscape orientation changes go here! */
}
```

Or if you want a javascript event you can bind to [orientationchange](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/api/events.html).

Comment: so from above code we have to set the different image size for both portrait and landscape. is this what you coming to say? if its yes mean how can we set the image size? because the different platform have different landscape screen size.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there are events that get triggered when the phone goes for landscape to portrait.You can however write a custom function to find out the current orientation. Write the following code on window.resize event.

```
$(window).resize( function(){
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();

if(width>height) {
  // Landscape
  $("#img").attr("src","landscapeurl");
} else {
  // Portrait
  $("#img").attr("src","portraiturl");
}
});
```

code from [Here](http://www.substanceofcode.com/2010/08/13/check-screen-orientation-with-jquery-in-w3c-widget/)

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to use CSS3 media queries as the jQuery mobile orientation classes are deprecated: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/mediahelpers.html

For a demo of CSS3 media queries: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

i use this css3 rule:

@media (orientation: landscape) {

```
#home-feature span  {
  display  : inline-block;
}
```

}

more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/